# Change class values at runtime

Tags: html, css

I have page that has 5 checkboxes

- Melbourne
- London
- Vancouver
- Paris
- Mecca

Each one of them represent a color

- Melbourne (Pink)
- London    (Blue)
- Vancouver (Red)
- Paris     (Yellow)
- Mecca     (Green)

in my html there is a long text with many words that are wrapped by a  and each span has class based on the city

when user tick the word Melbourne in the checkboxes, all words in the span and class melbourne will have background pink.

when it is un-ticked the background disappears

```
.Melbourne {
  background-color: pink;
}

.Vancouver {
  background-color: red;
}

            <div>
                <input id="cbxMelbourne" name="cbxMelbourne" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="cbxMelbourne">Melbourne</label>
                <input id="cbxVancouver" name="cbxVancouver" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="cbxVancouver">Vancouver</label>
                <input id="cbxLondon" name="cbxLondon" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="cbxLondon">London</label>

                </div>
```

Mark has left Doncaster East on monday and arrived to New Westminister on sunday.

    while Linda was living in Craigieburn her nephew was near by in Wanterna South and his friend still in London

The idea I have is to change the class values based on the checkbox tick

is this possible?

is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: Use `onchange` event, set a JS function

Comment: @Vaibhav JavaScript isn't needed at all. They can use the "checkbox trigger" trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP replied saying they absolutely have to use `<span>` - which means we have to use JavaScript.

Assuming you can't change **any** HTML (other than inserting a `<script>` into the `<head>` element) and adding CSS styles, then I'd do it like this:

```js
// Using a `Set` (which is a built-in Hashset type with O(1) lookup to avoid O(n) searches with a normal array).
const knownCities = new Set()
    .add( 'Melbourne' )
    .add( 'Vancouver' )
    .add( 'London' );

// Rather than adding `click` event-listeners on all <span> elements, it's easier to add a single listener to <body>. This has the advantage of meaning we can add more <span> elements to the document after it's loaded and not have to add event-listeners to them either.
document.body.addEventListener( 'click', onBodyClick );

function onBodyClick( ev ) {
    // first, verify that the click event was on a <span> that we're interested in:
    const el = ev.target;
    if( el.tagName == 'SPAN' && knownCities.has( el.className ) ) {
        
        // The `toggle` function will add "Melbourne", "Vancouver", etc to <body> if it isn't there already, otherwise it will remove it. This means we don't need to check for it ourselves.
        document.body.classList.toggle( el.className );
    }
}
```

```css
span.Melbourne,
span.Vancouver,
span.London {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: wavy;
}

body.Melbourne span.Melbourne {
    background-color: pink;
}

body.Vancouver span.Vancouver {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

body.London span.London {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
Mark has left <span class="Melbourne">Doncaster East</span> on monday and
arrived to <span class="Vancouver">New Westminister</span> on sunday.

while Linda was living in <span class="Melbourne">Craigieburn</span> her
nephew was near by in <span class="Melbourne">Wanterna South</span> and his
friend still in <span class="London">London</span>
```

Comment: can this be done when click on the checkbox                  <div>
                    <input id="cbxMelbourne" name="cbxMelbourne" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="cbxMelbourne">Melbourne</label>
     <input id="cbxVancouver" name="cbxVancouver" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="cbxVancouver">Vancouver</label>
     <input id="cbxLondon" name="cbxLondon" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="cbxLondon">London</label>
     
     </div>

Comment: @asmgx **You just completely changed the question** which invalidates both of my answers now. That's not cool. You should restore your original question (without the checkboxes) and repost a new question with the checkboxes.

Comment: first many thanks for your answers, the first sentance of my question i mentioned there are 5 checkboxes that i need to tick and untick. I thought it was clear, i just added the checkbox script to make clearer, again.. many thanks for your answers – asmgx just now   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS "checkbox trigger" trick, where you repurpose a hidden `<input type="checkbox" />` (or `radio`) to interactively restyle a page without the need for JavaScript:

```css
#melbourneTrigger,
#vancouverTrigger {
    display: none;
}

label[for] {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#melbourneTrigger:checked ~ .Melbourne,
#melbourneTrigger:checked ~ * .Melbourne,
#melbourneTrigger:checked ~ label[for=melbourneTrigger],
#melbourneTrigger:checked ~ * label[for=melbourneTrigger] {
     background-color: pink;
}

#vancouverTrigger:checked ~ .Vancouver,
#vancouverTrigger:checked ~ * .Vancouver,
#vancouverTrigger:checked ~ label[for=vancouverTrigger],
#vancouverTrigger:checked ~ * label[for=vancouverTrigger] {
     background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="melbourneTrigger" />
<input type="checkbox" id="vancouverTrigger" />

    <div>
        Mark has left <label for="melbourneTrigger">Doncaster East</label> on monday and
        arrived to <label for="vancouverTrigger">New Westminister</label> on sunday.

        while Linda was living in <label for="melbourneTrigger">Craigieburn</label> her
        nephew was near by in <label for="melbourneTrigger">Wanterna South</label> and his
        friend still in <label for="londonTrigger">London</span>
    </div>
```

Press the "Run code snippet" button to see it working.

Comment: Thanks, but the code is already built with <snap> and I have to use the checkbox tick value not to click on the text itself, can this be done?

Comment: @asmgx I think you mean `<span>`, not `<snap>` - I'll post a new reply now.

Comment: first many thanks for your answers, the first sentance of my question i mentioned there are 5 checkboxes that i need to tick and untick. I thought it was clear, i just added the checkbox script to make clearer, again.. many thanks for your answers